Adding DP to 0/1 knapsack
Here are the two different ways of solving 0/1 knapsack using recursion.
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define vi vector<int>
#define vb vector<bool>

long long solve1(int capacity, vi &weight, vi &value, vb &sacked){
    long long ans = 0;
    int n = weight.size();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        if(sacked[i] || weight[i]>capacity) continue;
        sacked[i]=true;
        ans = max(ans, value[i] + solve1(capacity-weight[i], weight, value, sacked));
        sacked[i]=false;
    }
    return ans;
}

long long solve2(int capacity, vi &weight, vi &value, int idx){
    if(idx==-1) return 0;
    long long ans = solve2(capacity, weight, value, idx-1);
    if(weight[idx]<=capacity) ans = max(ans, value[idx] + solve2(capacity-weight[idx], weight, value, idx-1));
    return ans;
}
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int n, c;
    cin>>n>>c;
    vi w(n), v(n);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) cin>>w[i]>>v[i];
    vb sacked(n, false);
    cout<<solve1(c, w, v, sacked)<<'\n';
    cout<<solve2(c, w, v, n-1);
}

I know how to add dp to the second method (in solve2 function). But I dont know how to add dp to the first method. As the true/false values in vector<bool> sacked will be unique for every call, using dp[capacity][sacked] seems useless as the same dp[capacity][sacked] will never be requested twice
"Am I wrong to conclude that value of vector<bool> sacked will be unique for every recursive function call and consequently DP for solve1 not possible?"

We're not doing code reviews here but here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. And please first learn C++ first. (so no #defines/ no long long, nor ios_base/tie)

Also never include #include<bits/stdc++.h> in your code it is not standard C++

It's not about adding dp to a method. As you correctly pointed out: the true/false values in vector sacked will be unique for every call using dp is useless here. The idea is to find reusable sub problems and use dp to avoid doing the same thing multiple times.

@PepijnKramer no. not in my context. using #include<bits/stdc++.h> is standard in competitive programming. could've just answered the question instead of going off topic

using ios_base/tie is essential to not get TLEs. so that was very unhelpful and backward advice. "learn c++ first" imagine telling a uni student to not experiment with algorithms before learning whole of c++ @PepijnKramer

Habits tend to stick, bad as well as good. Might as well use good habits and make them stick. All you're learning on such sites are bad habits, bad code, and too often also directly invalid code. If you present code like that in an interview, they will not blink before dismissing you. Learn the basics first, then use such sites for fun and entertainment on your spare time.

Why do you remove the C++ tag? The code is C++, so it's useful to have it. Otherwise you could get e.g. Lisp-specialist reading this and waste their time. If you have the C++ tag then people will know this is about C++ and the right people will look at it. Though, considering the code most will disregard it anyway.

@Someprogrammerdude I removed c++ because, I imagine more likes of @PepijnKramer going to arrive soon. I think i have worded it wrongly for ds/algorithms enthusiasts. It should be "Am I wrong to conclude that value of vector<bool> sacked to be unique for every recursive function call and consequently DP for solve1 not possible?"

@heman bits/stdc++ has NO runtime effect.. so you might as well use standard C++ techniques. The problem is that if I have to hire "compeitive coders", I need to retrain them to be engineers that can actually write maintainable code. Spoiler alert I will not.  TLE is all about the algorithm (and the only thing interviewers are interested is in how do you approach a problem), not that you can create the fastest code. Same is true for competitive coding (it is not about writing the fastest code) it is about finding the right algorithm

@heman I am not trying to be mean, just showing you there is a whole other side to C++ and software development that you may have missed :) And that techniques you take for granted are considered very bad practice in an actual job as software developer

@PepijnKramer same program without ios_base/tie DID give runtime effect. sorry but it has happened too many times that ios_base/tie is necessary even after writing the most optimal code, maybe its just a nuance in the way they handle input/outputs in codeforces, It is not required in leetcode. Its true that competitve coding and engineers are different and competitive coding is not writing maintainable code, I just had algorithmic question from the contest https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks

@PepijnKramer Competitive programming does often require I/O optimization, so suggesting the removal of ios_base::sync_with_stdio or cin.tie is not really an improvement. It is not just about the algorithm; if it were, contests could just involve submitting pseudocode. I prefer not using <bits/stdc++.h> as well, but actual contests also require solving the problems quickly so these includes are understandable.

@Unmitigated I think it is a problem of perspectives. I assume that the forum here is for asking questions to improve C++ knowledge. And that competitive coding sites have their own forum for competitive coding patterns. (Or at least SO is missing a competitive coding tag), because it seems the answers really depent on the perspective of the commenter otherwise

It is possible to memoize results for solve1 as well. For any particular choice of k elements, there are k! possible orders to arrive at that state, so the same answers can be requested multiple times.
The main issue with this method, however, is that the size of a state is quite large and the dynamic programming transition also takes linear time, which tends to be too inefficient to be practical.
Note that the 0/1 knapsack problem can be more simply and elegantly solved with tabulation.
#include <span>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
long long solve(int capacity, std::span<int> weights, std::span<int> values) {
    std::vector<long long> bestVal(capacity + 1);
    for (decltype(values.size()) i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = capacity; j >= weights[i]; --j)
            bestVal[j] = std::max(bestVal[j], bestVal[j - weights[i]] + values[i]);
    return bestVal.back();
}


So you mean sacked will not be unique for every call, and can be used to identify redundant subproblems? so i can memoize the function and just use dp[sacked] to get the cached value on repeated calls.

@heman It will not always be unique; you can indeed memoize it, but it will still be slower than the other method.
